# delete item from custom list , i am not able to find error , plz check my app.post

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

**plz check what's wrong in this code**
i have a custome list created in my to-do-list where i want the functionality to add and delete the list items and updates shold go to database as well,
but on delete item is not getting deleted..

### app.get()  , app.post() and list.ejs for custom list page

```
app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
  const customListName = _.capitalize(req.params.customListName);

  List.findOne({name: customListName}, function(err, foundList){
    if (!err){
      if (!foundList){
        //Create a new list
        const list = new List({
          name: customListName,
          items: defaultItems
        });
        list.save();
        res.redirect("/" + customListName);
      } else {
        //Show an existing list

        res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
      }
    }
  });



//..................................


 app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
    const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
    const listName = req.body.listName;

    if (listName === "Today") {
      Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Successfully deleted checked item.");
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
    } else {
      List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull: {items: {_id: checkedItemId}}}, function(err, foundList){
        if (!err){
          res.redirect("/" + listName);
        }
      });
    }


  });

//...................................


  <%  newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>

    <form action="/delete" method="post">
      <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <p><%=item.name%></p>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>"></input>
    </form>
  <%  }) %>
```